# renderizado duplicado en documento html

Tags: html, hosting

me pasaron un sitio echo en asp clásico, corre y se renderiza perfectamente en servidores locales con iis, pero al subirlo al hosting de godaddy empieza a hacer renderizados extraños con el doc html, no termina de generarlo y vuelve a empezar a generarlo por el encabezado nuevamente, lo que genera que se rompa todo el maquetado. alguna sugerencia?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

acá se puede ver como no termina de renderizar el doc y dentro de una etiqueta  comienza a renderizar nuevamente el documento.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Es importante hacer visible algo del código (o un ejemplo equivalente) para que otros sepan qué código genera esta salida. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).